# What are the files to exclude for syncing two azure vm?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, rsync

I tried to sync between two azure instances (same os distros) using Rsync; but after that, the target VM ssh connection not working, I think I missed some files to exclude.Any help ?

NOTE: The procedure was a success on other platforms, may be in my script I missed azure VM specific exclude files?

Steps to reproduce issue:

- Create two VMs with same os distros ( ubuntu 16.04 )
- run `rsync` command on source machine to sync files between ( use / excluding directories like /boot /etc/fstab /etc/hostname /etc/issue /etc/hosts etc.

`rsync -e "ssh -i keyfile" -rlpEAXogDtSzh -P -x --exclude-from="$excludefilelist" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --verbose --progress username@$TARGETVM_IP:/`

After syncing target vm seems to not running, note that am here used same ssh key files between those machines, username & group.

Comment: Cloud you please post your script here so that I can try to reproduce your issue in my lab.

Comment: Updated the question @StevenLee-MSFT & also verified the files it is ok, my question here is is there any Azure specific file i missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question here is is there any Azure specific file i missed ?

There are two packages installed on the Azure Ubuntu VM that may change the settings of the VM:

- Azure Linux Agent
- Cloud-Init

Running the command dpkg -L *PakageName* will give a list of files installed by the package. You may try to exclude all of these files.